# VB.NET login form - using Oracle

Tags: vb.net, oracle

In a Login form for `VB.Net` connected to an Oracle database.. Is there a way of inserting an If statement to direct different users to different forms.. Eg, an accountant to the accounting home page or a driver to a driver homepage even though all there ID's and passwords are in the one table within the database.
There is a `POSITION` field within the database and this is what I would like to use to differentiate the different users levels of access.
Here is the code working so far:

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

conn.ConnectionString = _
"Provider=msdaora;Data Source=orabis;User Id=112221800;Password=112221800;"


conn.Open()

Dim parmuser As New OleDb.OleDbParameter

parmuser.OleDbType = OleDb.OleDbType.Char

parmuser.Value = txtStaffNo.Text

Dim parmpass As New OleDb.OleDbParameter

parmpass.OleDbType = OleDb.OleDbType.Char

parmpass.Value = txtPassword.Text



Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

cmd.Connection = conn

cmd = New OleDbCommand("select STAFFID,PASSWORD from STAFF where STAFFID ='" & txtStaffNo.Text & "' and PASSWORD ='" & txtPassword.Text & "'", conn)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader



dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()


If txtStaffNo.Text = "" Or txtPassword.Text = "" Then

    MessageBox.Show("You have not entered any values!", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

ElseIf dr.Read() Then

    txtStaffNo.Text = dr("STAFFID")

    txtPassword.Text = dr("PASSWORD")

    MsgBox("Access Allowed")



    CustOption.Show()
    Me.Hide()

Else

    'MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username and Password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    'intCount = intCount + 1



End If
```

Comment: You should not: (1) construct queries by concatenating user input, never, especially on a login test ([SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) and (2) [store password in plain text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270485/password-management-best-practices-soup-to-nuts-not-just-storage-or-generation)

Answer (score 0):

In your SELECT statement, add position there so it would be:

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("select POSITION, STAFFID,PASSWORD from STAFF where STAFFID ='" & txtStaffNo.Text & "' and PASSWORD ='" & txtPassword.Text & "'", conn)
```

Then after you validate the user, you just use a select case like:

```
Dim empPosition as string = dr("POSITION") ' assuming it's a string here
select case empPosition.toLower
   case "driver"
      ' open driver form
   case "accountant"
       'open accountant form
    ' more case statements for other positions.
End Select
```